# Number triangle using while loops

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble with my C++ programming class homework.

**Here is the assignment:**

Write a program which reads in the number of rows and prints 'n' rows
 of digits.

> 1
>
> 12
>
> 123
>
> 1234
>
> 12345

where the i’th row is 1234 . . . k where k = i mod 10. If a row
 has more than 10 digits, the digit after 9 should start again from 0.
 For instance, if the number of rows is 15, the output should be: 1

> 12
>
> 123
>
> 1234
>
> 12345
>
> 123456
>
> 1234567
>
> 12345678
>
> 123456789
>
> 1234567890
>
> 12345678901
>
> 123456789012
>
> 1234567890123
>
> 12345678901234
>
> 123456789012345

**This is what I have so far:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int rows(0);
    int i(0);
    int j(0);

    cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
    cin >> rows;

    int k=rows;
    i=1;

    while (i <= rows)
    {  
        j=1;
        while(j <= i)
    {
        cout << j;
        j++;
    }
        cout << endl ;
        i++;
    }

    return (0);
}
```

This works perfectly until I get to the 10th row. I'm not sure how to get the counter to reset back to 0 and go 1-9 again. I'm guessing an `if` statement, but I don't know how to correctly implement it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your posts will get more attention if you'll properly format your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `cout << j%10` will always print the ones digit of whatever `j` is equal to.  So when `j = 10`, `cout << j%10` will print `0`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the other answer a bit:

`%` is referred to as the remainder operator. It is also sometimes called "modulo" or "modulus". It returns the remainder of the first argument divided by the second argument. So for this situation, since you want the number to be between 0 and 9, consider what happens when you have `n % 10`.

```
8 / 10 == 0 remainder 8
9 / 10 == 0 remainder 9
10 / 10 == 1 remainder 0
11 / 10 == 1 remainder 1
12 / 10 == 1 remainder 2
```

Etc.

In C++, as in most programming languages, you typically start counting at 0 and you exclude the final number in your range. So if you had `n % 56`, your output starting at 0 would go up to 55, and then reset to 0 again. The classical argument for this was written by Dijkstra:

http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html